# Inequalities based on arithmetic progression

Tags: inequality, contest-math

Let $m_1<m_2<m_3<\cdots <m_{k-1}<m_k$ are positive integers where their reciprocals are in arithmetic progression. Show that $k<m_1+2$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $a_1,a_2\dots$ be the underlying arithmetic progression.

Then $a_1=\frac{1}{m_1},a_2=\frac{1}{m_2}\implies a_n=\frac{m_2+1-n}{m1m2}\implies m_n=\frac{m_2m_1}{m_2+1-n}$.

So $m_2=\frac{m_2m_1}{m_2-1}\implies m_1=m_2-1$.

So your sequence is:

$m_n=\frac{m_1(m_1+1)}{m_1+2-n}$. Therefore the term $m_a$ is undefined for $a=m_1+2$, so $k<m_1+2$.